# SCCM OS Upgrade Package task sequence fails

Tags: windows-10, sccm

So I added 1903 as an OS Upgrade Package into my 1902 SCCM, and, when I try the task sequence, it fails. (I'm attempting to upgrade Windows 10 1809 to 1903)

The scanresult.xml tells me this, but it doesn't tell me what oem19.inf and oem18.inf are.

How can I find out?:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use SetupDiag to analyse in-place upgrade failures from the resulting logs

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2018/04/05/windows-10-new-tool-setupdiag-tool-diagnose-problems-with-win7win8-1win10-to-a-win10-upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

Just disabling the "Check Readiness" step took me past this. SetupDiag didn't really help, it couldn't find anything wrong. (machine already met all resource critera)